# Angular-CLI: Where is the App Module?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, recycle-bin

Feel free to skim what I did, it's pretty typical. Used angular-cli to generate an app:

> ng start

Created a component:

> ng generate component user-item

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-user-item',
  templateUrl: 'user-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['user-item.component.css']
})
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Then I included my new component in the root component which gets bootstrap by adding the selector to the html:  `<app-user-item></app-user-item>`. This is supposed to "just work" according to NG-Book2, but it doesn't. Angular 2 official documentation tells us to include the new component in the imports (ES6) and providers(NG2 module) of the module, as well as the root component. But I guess that's due to a different build - I tried including the component import in the bootstrapped "root" component and main.ts, which didn't do anything (app still works without the new component showing up).

How do I get this to work with angular-cli? Do I really not need to include it in the the module/component via imports?

Edit:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

gets me

```
angular-cli@0.0.39
```

So maybe that's the cause, but the npm list (not global) angular cli version shows as:

```
angular-cli@0.1.0
```

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of angular-cli installed `v1.0.0-beta19`. I'm using it without any issues.

Comment: @DawidZbiński I just installed it today, checking version now. So you are able to just do: 1. Use the ng generate command 2. Insert the selector in the html, and that's it? It "just works"?

Comment: You need to initialize the directory with `ng new your_dir` or `ng init / ng start`, then you want to create the component so `ng g c your_component`. This is going to be automatically inserted to your app.module.ts file and now wherever you want to use this component you need to import it in your parent component and then you can use it in template as you did.

Comment: Let's say you want to use it in your root app.component.ts .. you go there and import your_component from your_component/your_component.component.ts .. then in your template you include that component selector, so `<your_components_selector></your_components_selector>`. And that's it.

Comment: Thanks Dawid - that's what I was doing, looks like there is a problem with my build or whatever, but the point is that it doesn't work for me in particular, so its probably some silly mistake - that's good to know.

Comment: does not... just work.    having the exact same problem as the author.  using the absolute LATEST bleeding edge angular-cli,  uninstalled, cleaned cache, everything.   ng new whatever / ng g component mycomponent, add it in the template, import it, whatever, does not work.  shows up in the HTML as a empty templated tag.  something is not right.

Comment: @Zuriel I had to delete node, install latest, and reinstall all my global packages. It worked eventually, so I am guessing it has something to do with that.  Just tried it yesterday on diff computer, so I am guessing latest version is ok. Good luck.

Comment: @VSO yes, you are right i just got it, for anyone else who has trouble, you are suppose to do this.
1)  npm uninstall -g angular-cli
2)  npm cache clean
3)  npm install -g angular-cli@latest

after doing that, and recreating an app, it works! i have a ng modules folder as well as nested components

| => ng --version
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.22-1